# Using offsetof() to get pointer to member for member-agnostic functions

Tags: c, struct, casting, pointer-to-member, offsetof

Suppose I have a `struct` like:

```
typedef struct S S;
struct S {
    S *next;
    // ...
    S *gc_next;
};
```

I.e., it contains multiple "next" pointers to be simultaneously on multiple linked lists. If I want to write a single function that can follow *any* "next" pointer, I can pass the offset of which "next" pointer I want, e.g.:

```
void S_free_impl( S *p, size_t next_offset ) {
    while ( p ) {
        S *next = *PTR_OFFSET( p, S*, next_offset );
        free( p );
        p = next;
    }
}
```

where `PTR_OFFSET` is a macro that, given a pointer to some `struct`, the type of the member I want (in this case, `S*`), and the offset of the member I want, then dereferencing that pointer, I can get the value of the wanted member.

To get the offset, I can write a front-end macro to call `S_free_impl()` that uses `offsetof`:

```
#define S_FREE(PTR,NEXT)         S_free_impl( (PTR), offsetof( S, NEXT ) )
```

then use it like:

```
S_FREE( p, gc_next );            // free nodes following "gc_next" pointer
```

An initial implementation of the `PTR_OFFSET` macro can be:

```
#define PTR_OFFSET(PTR,TYPE,OFFSET) \
    (TYPE*)((char*)(PTR) + (OFFSET))
```

However, if you compile, say, using `gcc -Wcast-align`, you get:

```
foo.c:21:24: warning: cast from 'char *' to 'S **' (aka 'struct S **') increases
      required alignment from 1 to 8 [-Wcast-align]
            S *next = *PTR_OFFSET( p, S*, next_offset );
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

One way to suppress the warning, is to write a sort-of C equivalent of C++'s `reinterpret_cast`:

```
#define REINTERPRET_CAST(T,EXPR)  ((T)(uintptr_t)(EXPR))
```

then rewrite `PTR_OFFSET` to use it:

```
#define PTR_OFFSET(PTR,TYPE,OFFSET) \
    REINTERPRET_CAST( TYPE*, REINTERPRET_CAST( char*, (PTR) ) + (OFFSET) )
```

then the warning goes away because of casting *through* a `uintptr_t`.

---

The question is: is this the best (most portable) way to get what I want in C? Specifically:

1. The ability to write functions that operate on different `struct` members (of the same type).
2. A portable way to *use* the value returned by `offsetof` to convert it to an actual pointer-to-member.

Comment: Why are there so many `S` present?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand your question.

Comment: You could try `(TYPE *)(void *)` to avoid the warning.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, but that's hardly different from using `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @melpomene Actually, if you want `REINTERPRET_CAST` to be totally generic, casting to `(void*)` will _not_ work because if you cast, say, `unsigned` via `(void*)`, `gcc -Wint-to-void-pointer-cast` will generate a "cast to void* from smaller integer type" warning. Using `uintptr_t` works in that case too.